# Summarising output from MySQL query

Tags: mysql, select, aggregate

I am trying to summarize the output of a query but am struggling. The query below checks the fax_authorized table and generates a summary of extensions with email addresses against them.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT extended_number, IF(COUNT(extension_id)<5,1,0) AS 'fax5', 
  IF(COUNT(extension_id)>5 AND COUNT(extension_id)<11,1,0) AS 'fax10',
  IF(COUNT(extension_id)>10,1,0) AS 'fax10+', COUNT(extension_id) AS 'fax_total'
FROM fax_authorized fa, extension e
WHERE fa.extension_id = e.id
GROUP BY extended_number;
```

The output looks like this:

```
+-----------------+------+-------+--------+-----------+
| extended_number | fax5 | fax10 | fax10+ | fax_total |
+-----------------+------+-------+--------+-----------+
| 0009*004        |    1 |     0 |      0 |         1 |
| 0139*601        |    0 |     1 |      0 |         6 |
| 0139*743        |    1 |     0 |      0 |         2 |
| 0139*996        |    1 |     0 |      0 |         1 |
+-----------------+------+-------+--------+-----------+
```

What I would like is to summarize this data based on LEFT(extended_number,4) so that for example 0139 above would have fax5=2, fax10=1, fax_total=9.

I have tried this, which doesn't work:

```
SELECT extended_number, SUM(IF(COUNT(extension_id)<5,1,0)) AS 'fax5',   
  SUM(IF(COUNT(extension_id)>5 AND COUNT(extension_id)<11,1,0)) AS 'fax10', 
  SUM(IF(COUNT(extension_id)>10,1,0)) AS 'fax10+', 
  COUNT(LEFT(extension_id,4)) AS 'fax_total'
FROM fax_authorized fa, extension e
WHERE fa.extension_id = e.id
GROUP BY LEFT(extended_number,4);
```

Edit: I used the answer of Saharsh Shah below to solve this issue, but hit another one which I thought was worth adding. I tried to create a view from his nested subquery solution but was unable to, as subqueries aren't allowed in views. So I created two related views as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_xoom_faxdetail AS 
  SELECT LEFT(extended_number,4) client_id, 
   IF(COUNT(extension_id)<5,1,0) AS 'fax5', 
   IF(COUNT(extension_id)>5 AND COUNT(extension_id)<11,1,0) AS 'fax10',
   IF(COUNT(extension_id)>10,1,0) AS 'fax10plus', 
   COUNT(extension_id) AS 'fax_total'
 FROM fax_authorized fa, extension e WHERE fa.extension_id = e.id
 GROUP BY client_id;

CREATE VIEW vw_xoom_fax AS 
 SELECT client_id, SUM(fax5) fax5, SUM(fax10) fax10,
  SUM(fax10plus) 'fax10+', SUM(fax_total) fax_total 
 FROM vw_xoom_faxdetail
 GROUP BY client_id;
```

Comment: What do you mean by faulty?

Comment: @Jack - sorry I meant it doesn't work, just gives me a syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT extended_number, SUM(fax5) fax5, SUM(fax10) fax10, SUM(fax10plus) 'fax10+', SUM(fax_total) fax_total 
FROM (SELECT LEFT(extended_number,4) extended_number, IF(COUNT(extension_id)<5,1,0) AS 'fax5', 
             IF(COUNT(extension_id)>5 AND COUNT(extension_id)<11,1,0) AS 'fax10',
       IF(COUNT(extension_id)>10,1,0) AS 'fax10plus', COUNT(extension_id) AS 'fax_total'
      FROM fax_authorized fa, extension e WHERE fa.extension_id = e.id
      GROUP BY extended_number) AS A 
GROUP BY extended_number;
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks. So I understand this correctly, your solution is to nest my aggregate query inside another? I was confused a little by the use of extended_number in both the inner and outer query, when in fact in the outer query it is only the left hand 4 characters of the extended_number.

Comment: I now have another issue - I wanted to create a view from this query to use in my DB, however I'm getting an error: ERROR 1349 (HY000): View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Comment: Turns out subqueries aren't allowed in view definitions - have edited the question to show how I created two related view definitions instead.